# Como utilizo sendmessage?

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, lazarus, object-pascal

Estou conseguindo obter a lista de classes dos recursos de outra aplicação mas não acho classes do tipo Button, edits ou labels e vejo que a aplicação tem estes recursos.

Este é meu código:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
hWindow : THandle;
hChild : THandle;
aTemp : array[0..5000] of Char;
sClassName : String;
sCaption : String;
Result: string;
begin
  Result := '';
  sCaption := 'Nome do Programa';
  hWindow := FindWindow(Nil,PChar(sCaption));

  if hWindow = 0 then
  begin
     ShowMessage('Could NOT find the other program');
    exit;
  end;

  hChild := GetWindow(hWindow, GW_HWNDFIRST);
  while hChild <> 0 do
     Begin
     if GetClassName(hChild, aTemp, SizeOf(aTemp)) > 0 then
        begin

        sClassName := StrPAS(aTemp);
        Memo1.Lines.Add(sClassName);
        if sClassName = 'Label' then
           begin
           SendMessage(hChild,WM_GETTEXT,SizeOf(aTemp),Integer(@aTemp));
           Result := StrPAS(aTemp);
           Memo1.Lines.Add('     '+Result);
        end;
     end;
  hChild := GetWindow(hChild, GW_HWNDNEXT);
  end;
end;
```

Então obtenho algo como :

```
tooltips_class32
ForegroundStaging
IME
ForegroundStaging
tooltips_class32
```

Não acho nada sobre isto na internet, como faço para obter os recursos tipo:

```
lblCalculado
edtValor
btnComprar
btnVender
```

ou

Já testei com GW_CHILD, GW_OWNER, GW_HWNDPRIOR/NEXT/FIRST/LAST e não consigo.

Obrigado

Comment: Pesquise por FindComponent, com ele consegue ter uma lista de todos os componentes do form e manipulá-lo conforme necessidade.

Answer (score 0):

Declare no Uses EnumWindowUtil; e tente essa função:

```
function PegaHandlesFilhos(h: HWnd): string;
var 
wlistChilds     : TWindowList;
begin
    try
        wlistChilds := TWindowList.Create;
        wlistChilds.AddClassname := True;
        wlistChilds.EnumChildWindows(h);
        result := wlistChilds.Text;
    except
    end;
end;

//EXEMPLO
Memo1.text:= PegaHandlesFilhos(0); //Altere o 0 pelo handle principal
```